# Getting SUM of test scores for a certain user using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to get the SUM of scores from a table which has this structure:

| StudentID | TestName | Earned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1. First | 100 |
| 3 | 2. Second | 95 |
| 3 | 3. Third | 82 |
| 3 | 4. Fourth | 92 |

I have this code:

```
"SELECT SUM(Earned) as Score FROM table WHERE TestName=First and TestName=Third and StudentID=3"
```

But I get 0 retuned as a result.  I need to retrieve multiple test scores and I'd rather learn the right way to do it with one query than make multiple queries.  Thank you.

Comment: It returns 0 results because there are no rows matching your `WHERE` description. There can be no `TestName` row that matches both `First` and `Third` values at the same time. Try using `OR` instead. I created this fiddle in case it clears things up  https://dbfiddle.uk/C1S_a-rd .

Comment: *`.. WHERE TestName=First and TestName=Third.. `* - you try to find the row where `TestName` is equal to `First` and `Third` **at the same time**. Of course you can find nothing..

Comment: Thanks Izanagi! Works perfect!  I'm new to this MYSQL stuff, very much appreciate your help.